# Why does my condition always evaluate as true?

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm writing my first bash script and I've hit a snag.  Here's an example where I ask for a name, ask for an age, and display a message that changes depending on whether or not the age is <= 35:

```
#!/bin/bash
ageLimit = 34
echo "What is your name?"
read userName
echo "How old are you?"
read userAge
if (( "$userAge" -le "$ageLimit" )); then
    echo "Hey, $userName.  At $userAge years old, you are young."
else
    echo "Gosh, $userName.  At $userAge years old, you're pretty old."
fi
```

No matter what number I answer for age, I am told I am young.  This is running on Raspbian -- in case that helps.  Thanks!

Jeremy

Comment: [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Comparison Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) would be a good reference..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whitespaces make a lot of difference in whell script, you need to take care of them. There is no space between the variable name and the `=` sign and its value.

Rewrite your shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
ageLimit=34
echo "What is your name?"
read userName
echo "How old are you?"
read userAge
if [[ "$userAge" -le "$ageLimit" ]]; then
    echo "Hey, $userName.  At $userAge years old, you are young."
else
   echo "Gosh, $userName.  At $userAge years old, you're pretty old."
fi
```

Refer to a good tutorial on shell scripting while you make your hands dirty. One good tutorial googling returns is this:

- [Linux Shell Scripting Tutorial v1.05r3
  A Beginner's handbook by Vivek G. Gite](http://doc.dev.md/lsst/ch02.html)

You may also want to know this:

- [Difference between single and double square brackets in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/bash-if-difference-between-square-brackets-and-double-square-brackets)

Comment: Awesome, Jobin.  Works beautifully.  And thanks for the links!  I'm loving learning this.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I can see two minor errors in your code.

[1] Do not use space while declaring variable, do like this

```
ageLimit=34
```

[2] There is two ways of putting `if` conditions, use either of it.

```
if [ "$userAge" -le "$ageLimit" ]; then
```

or

```
if (( "$userAge" <= "$ageLimit" )); then
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are try to evaluate two string then use the -le -ge if you want to evaluate the number i suggest you to use the conventional operator  > <= it is general convention and wars good. 
so in this case 
use

> if [ "$userAge" -le "$ageLimit" ]; then else fi